# Error: nls models, parameters without starting value

Tags: r, parameters, nls

I'm finalizing my analysis through R Studio but I keep getting the following error:

> Error in nls(Lambda ~ (exp(a + (b * AvgTemp) + (c * (AvgTempSQ)))) * ((f +  : 
>     parameters without starting value in 'data': Lambda, AvgTemp, AvgTempSQ, Avg9mpl2

I'm using an `nls` model on my data which are of marine turtles populations. Example of the data:

```
    Year  NestNo  Nnx  AvgTemp  AvgTempSQ    DeltaT    Avg9m   Avg9mpl2  Delta9m  DeltaT6mo  Lambda
```

```
 1  2001    200   169 28.34775  803.5952 -0.076099458 26.34428 26.36894 -0.03816773  1.17096134  0.845
 2  2003    169   217 28.27166  799.2865 -0.495949490 26.30612 26.19357 -0.44005462 -0.73101383  1.284023669
 3  2005    217   173 27.77571  771.4898 -0.001267699 25.86606 25.72760 -0.19400921  0.13683564  0.797235023
 4  2007    173   177 27.77444  771.4194  0.673155356 25.67205 25.14554 -0.01314047  0.04514593  1.023121387
 5  2009    177   242 28.44759  809.2656 -0.004746753 25.65891 26.40294  0.69639187  0.50118280  1.367231638
 6  2011    242   169 28.44285  808.9955 -0.155921769 26.35530 25.82456 -0.58788274  0.57365957  0.698347107
 7  2013    169   204 28.28692  800.1501  0.691692622 25.76742 25.87135  0.93487967 -0.13337923  1.207100592
 8  2002    160   155 28.43327  808.4508 -0.442880957 26.36893 26.30611 -0.17536234 -0.101341    0.96875
 9  2004    155   152 27.99038  783.4619 -0.300705456 26.19357 25.86606 -0.46597795 -0.63660134  0.980645161
 10 2006    152   166 27.68968  766.7186  0.343648365 25.72759 25.67205 -0.58205608 -0.6011307   1.092105263
 11 2008    166   230 28.03333  785.8677  0.445561426 25.14554 25.65891  1.25739876  1.5878006   1.385542169
 12 2010    230   171 28.47889  811.0474 -0.212961260 26.40294 26.35530 -0.57838339 -0.65363244  0.743478261
 13 2012    171   210 28.26593  798.9630  0.594340979 25.82456 25.76742  0.04679609 -0.13760156  1.228070175
 14 2014    210   229 28.86027  832.9154           NA 25.87135 26.70230  0.56480857  0.36140641  1.09047619
```

When running the model I keep getting the error mentioned above. The model is the following:

```
nstart <- list(a=-119.95838,b=8.59843,c=-0.15402,f=0,g=0,h=0)
w <- list(999,999,999,999,999,999)
s <-list(-999,-999,-999,-999,-999,-999)
model <- nls(Lambda~(exp(a+(b*AvgTemp)+(c*(AvgTempSQ))))*
    ((f+(g*Avg9mpl2)+(h*(Avg9mpl2^2)))/(f+(g*Avg9mpl2)+
    (h*(Avg9mpl2^2)))),
   upper=w,lower=s,start=nstart,algorithm="port")
summary(model)
```

I would appreciate your help on the above.

Comment: You don't appear to be passing your data to the `nls()` function anywhere. See [how to create a reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) for ways to share data such that we can copy/paste into R for testing.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I have updated the question above.

Comment: `Lambda` is not available in your dataset.

Comment: I'm not sure what you've called your data.frame where you've stored your data, but if you called it `mydata`, then add `data=mydata` to your `nls()` call.